# Setting focus on a TextField when application starts when there are two states

Tags: apache-flex, cursor, focus, state, textinput

I have next application header:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init()" creationPolicy="all" enterState="focusManager.setFocus(employeeIDTextInput);">

public function init():void {
    focusManager.showFocusIndicator = true;
    focusManager.showFocus();
    focusManager.setFocus(theTextInput);
}
```

And theTextInput is on the default state. But when application starts theTextField is focused (a blue rectangle is around theTextField) but the cursor isn't inside theTextField. But in the next state I have anotherTextInput and when you switch between states both text inputs are focused correctly as you expect and the cursor appears inside every one of them correctly.

```
<mx:State name="secondState" enterState="{focusManager.setFocus(anotherTextInput)}">
```

My question is, Why when application starts the cursor isn't inside theTextInput as commanded on init() function?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Did you try running your function on applicationComplete instead of creationComplete ?

Comment: When your browser loads the SWF, the SWF should be given focus via JavaScript (or by manually clicking on it). If you try either of these, does the cursor appear in the text input?

Comment: user1875642 The applicationComplete event is not dispatched in components.

Comment: Suni D. I don't know how to make that in javascrip

Comment: @YuryEuceda applicationComplete is Dispatched after the application has been initialized, processed by the LayoutManager, and attached to the display list. This is the last event dispatched during an application’s startup sequence. It is later than the application’s creationComplete event, which gets dispatched before the preloader has been removed and the application has been attached to the display list.

Comment: as to what Sunil D. suggested, see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921690/how-do-i-make-my-flash-object-get-focus-on-load

Answer (score 2):

I solved it, That problem was because this is a component and is called from a main menu, and the creationComplete event is dispatched just in the moment when the menu is created just before the component appears in screen. What I did was to attach an event handler to show event and that is.

```
<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
       creationComplete="init()" creationPolicy="all"
       show="focusManager.setFocus(employeeIDTextInput)"
       >
```

Thank you very much to every one who ask my question...