# (Actionscript 3.0) How to fix this arrow control glitch?

Tags: actionscript-3

Currently, I am trying to make a game, but I ran into a couple of problems. 
One of them is that I have to click the screen for the arrow controls to work. Is there anyway to fix that?

Secondly, the arrow keys work as intended, but the WASD keys do not. Why is that?

```
private function key_down(event:KeyboardEvent): void{
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == 65){
            leftPressed=true;  
        }
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT || event.keyCode == 68){
            rightPressed=true;
        }
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == 87){
            upPressed=true;
        }
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || event.keyCode == 83){
            downPressed=true;
        }
    }
    private function key_up(event:KeyboardEvent): void{
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == 65){
            leftPressed=false;
        }
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT || event.keyCode == 68){
            rightPressed=false;
        }
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == 87){
            upPressed=false;
        }
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || event.keyCode == 83){
            downPressed=false;
        }
    }
```

Note: In another part of the code, I defined how the player moves if leftPressed, rightPressed, downPressed and upPressed is true or false.

Comment: Focus: you need to focus your Flash object in HTML page on load: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921690/how-do-i-make-my-flash-object-get-focus-on-load Keys: you need to use event.charCode instead of event.keyCode

Comment: Your code works perfectly well for me with WASD and event.keyCode. Obviously, the keyboardEvent listener must target the stage. Could you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: Apparently, only on my computer, the WASD keys do not work. When I try playing the game on other computers, the WASD keys work perfectly well. That is strange.

Comment: That is very strange. A tip: Use Keyboard.A rather than 65, it makes reading code later way easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simplified version of your code, which you should test directly in an .fla file:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);

var leftPressed:Boolean;

function keydown(event:KeyboardEvent): void
{
    //if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == 65)
    if(event.keyCode == 65)
    {
        leftPressed=true;  
        trace('left Pressed');
    }

}
```

Notice that I've commented-out the Keyboard.LEFT line and replaced it with a line
that tests only for the 'a' key. This should work on your system.